# Is there a term for when a word is repeated with a different starting consonant?

Tags: terminology

I've heard this used in speech, not written language, and specifically in South Asian languages like Bengali/Hindi/Urdu (or in English by South Asian people who know English as a second language).

Examples in English include "jacket facket" or "watch totch" or "piano fiano". I think the replacement consonants are usually f-, t-, or sh-, although this is purely observational.

Comment: It's shm- or just m- in Southeastern Europe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is called "echo reduplication", for example Hindi *jānā-vānā* "going etc.", *ālū-vālū* "potato etc." or in Tamil *tummi kimmi* "sneezing etc". More generally (outside Indian linguistics) in the theoretical literature it is known as reduplication with fixed segmentalism.

Answer (score 2):

There is also the shm- reduplicating prefix in American East-Coast English, originally from Yiddish. A good general designation would be "rhyme formations" or "echo words".

Comment: It's a form of reduplication, which may or may not have the initial consonant cluster specified (as it is in Yiddish [_shm_-reduplication](https://www.revolvy.com/page/Shm%252Dreduplication)).